# SPItemEventReceiver for a new document added

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How Can Add an "SPItemEventReceiver".ItemAdded when a new document is uploaded to a document library ?

I have an Sharepoint solution and I want to fire the SPItemEventReceiver from a file update to a Library document.

It will be always EXCEL files that will be placed in that Document Library.

After a new Excel is uploaded to the DL i need to open this Excel file and treat this data.

Comment: Please extend your question a bit by adding more details on what you want to do, what tools you have access to, and other useful information (like SharePoint version e.g)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://vithunsharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/11/sharepoint-2010-event-handler-list-item.html) is a good example, that shows how to create sharepoint event handlers step by step.

To [read](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.in/2011/10/read-content-of-uploaded-file-within.html) the content of the file on itemAdded event:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  string searchForFileName = Path.GetFileName(properties.BeforeUrl);
  HttpFileCollection collection = _context.Request.Files;
   for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
   {
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = collection[i];
     if (searchForFileName.Equals(
      Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
        Stream fileStream = postedFile.InputStream;
        fileStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] fileContents = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength];
        fileStream.Read(fileContents, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
        ...
```

To [Read](http://www.sharepointwithattitude.com/archives/61) the Excel file content:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdate = true;
string workbookPath = web.Url + "/" + item.Url;

ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
excel.Visible = false;
Workbook excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, 
true,5,"","",false,XlPlatform.xlWindows,"",true,false,0,true,false,false);

Sheets sheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)Sheets.get_Item(1);
Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1","M500");
ExcelValues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value2;

excel.Workbooks.Close();
```